# How to package my python project to be runnable from command line?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, twine

I've coded my python project and have succeeded in publishing it to test pypi. However, now I can't figure out how to correctly configure it as a console script. Upon running `my_project` on the command line, I get the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thatcoolcoder/.local/bin/my_project", line 5, in <module>
    from my_project.__main__ import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'
```

Clearly, it's created a script to run but the script is then failing to import my actual code.

Folder structure:

```
pyproject.toml
setup.cfg
my_project
├── __init__.py (empty)
├── __main__.py
```

Relevant sections of `setup.cfg`:

```
[metadata]
name = my-project
version = 1.0.5

...

[options]
package_dir =
    = my_project
packages = find:

...

[options.packages.find]
where = my_project

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    my_project = my_project.__main__:main
```

`pyproject.toml` (probably not relevant)

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel"
]
```

`__main__.py`:

```
from my_project import foo

def main():
    foo.bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To build and upload, I'm running the following: (`python` is python 3.10)

```
python -m build
python -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

Then to install and run:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/pypi/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple my-project --upgrade

my_project
```

How can I make this console script work?

Also, this current method of setting `console_scripts` only allows it to be run as `my_project`; is it possible to also make it work by `python -m my_project`? Or perhaps this will work once my main issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got back to this problem today and it appears that I was using an incorrect source layout, which caused the pip module installation to not work. I switched to a directory structure like this one:

```
├── src
│   └── mypackage
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── mod1.py
├── setup.py
└── setup.cfg
```

and modified the relevant parts of my `setup.cfg`:

```
[options]
package_dir=
    =src
packages=find:

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

Then I can run it like `python -m mypackage`. This also made the console scripts work. It works on Linux but I presume it also works on other systems.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny, but I had the same frustration when trying to install scripts on multiple platforms. (As Python calls them; `posix` and `nt`.)

So I wrote [setup-py-script](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/setup-py-script) in 2020. It's up on github now.

It installs scripts that use their own modules as a self-contained zip-file. (This method was inspired by `youtube-dl`.) That means no more leftover files when you delete a script but forget to remove the module et cetera.

It does *not* require root or administrator privileges; installation is done in user-accessible directories.

You might have to structure your project slightly differently; the script itself is not in the module directory. See the project README.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'd prefer a pure twine/pip method with no external libraries since it appears to be possible (pip manages to do this, so does http.server). I will try your script if I get no other answers, however.

Comment: The setup scripts have no dependencies outside of Python's standard library. And since you copy them into your project, they're hardly external. But good luck, and let us know whet you find.